# Binding WPF DataTemplate to Dictionary <int, Page>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary

So I'm trying to bind a XAML DataTemplate to a Dictionary.
Example:

```js
pages: {
    1: {
        thumb: "https://www.sample.com",
        image: "https://www.sample.com"
    },
    2: {
        thumb: "https://www.sample.com",
        image: "https://www.sample.com"
    }
}
```

And so on.

Basically, I'm getting a variable number of pages for each request, and I solved the dynamic deserialization by creating a Dictionary with the key/values , but I can't seem to find a way to bind said Dictionary to a XAML DataTemplate.

In this particular view, I am trying to display a grid of the 'thumb' images from a given Content item.  Any ideas on how I'm supposed to approach this?  Preferably something that can be easily done with ItemsSource or Binding, or such, if there is such a way.

Comment: have you created view models for the same? what is the expected output for the sample data in the question? perhaps post a screenshot for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I think I found a work-around.
The images are bound to an Image within a DataTemplate in the ListBox I have set up.
I was looking for a way to have one ListBox with a WrapPanel, which would display images from a dictionary - in this case, the thumbs of each page within the dictionary, of which has a variable number of `<int>` Keys.

While I would like to know if it is possible to bind the Image Source to a dictionary like I have described above, I found I can use this for the time being:

```cs
private static void GenerateThumbsAndImages()
    {
        foreach (Page i in CurrentContentInfo.Pages.Values)
        {
            PageImages.Add(new Uri(i.image));
            PageThumbs.Add(new Uri(i.thumb));
        }
    }
```

Which I then bound with my XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ThumbView" ItemsSource="{x:Static local:Posts.PageThumbs}" ... >
<Image x:Name="PageThumbnailImage" Source="{Binding OriginalString}" ... />
```

If anybody knows how I could bind directly to the dictionary, that'd be great, but this works fine for now.